# Click-Event on iframe without javascript

Tags: php, html, iframe

I need a iframe with link attached to that iframe. I have a iframe with src containing image file and id containing the url where i should be navigated. I should not use javascript or any php coding for link creation. when i paste that iframe in any page, its should be a clickable iframe.

adding  tag doesn work in some browsers like chrome and firefox.

Eg:

```
<iframe src="imagepath" scrolling = "no" width="728" height="90" id = "redirect url"></iframe>
```

Comment: this is my iframe tag: <iframe src="image path" scrolling = "no" width="728" height="90" id = "redirect url"></iframe>

Comment: I don't understand you...

Comment: Can't you just wrap it in an `<a>` tag? `<a href=""><iframe></iframe></a>` - or maybe you should just make the contents of the iframe clickable.

Comment: @user3201900: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With the following HTML and CSS you get an iframe with a link overlay. You have to specify the `redirect url` in the `a` tag. If you you really have to specify it in the `id` of the `iframe`, you definitely need JavaScript.

Here's a demo how it looks like (only tested in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/2kA3J/

CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;    
}

#container a {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#container iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="redirect url"></a>
    <iframe src="imagepath" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
```